# How to assign ACL to UI component Form in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, acl

I need to assign acl to Ui Component Form? Anyone know about it?

Comment: Okay, But please i need answer in Magento2?

Comment: are  you need ACL for the particular button action?

Comment: No, Actually i need display some UI component field based on ACL? How to achieve it?

Comment: Are you display form fields based on ACL right?

Comment: Yea yes correct

Comment: Please answer me

Comment: I am checking my end. Still not found solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75298/discussion-between-ramanathan-and-abdul).